# regex match preceding word but not word itself

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression for matching a word that immediately precedes a keyword, but doesn't match the keyword itself.  For example, in the following text:

```
"this is some text keyword"
```

the regex expression should match "text" (assuming "keyword" is the keyword).  I should also note that the keyword will always appear as the last word on a line.  So far I've come up with this regex:

```
((?:\S+\s)?\S*keyword\n)
```

but that matches both the preceding word and the keyword itself (so in the above example it would match "text keyword" instead of just "text").  Does anyone have any advice for this?  I'm still learning regex.
Thank you!!

Comment: `\w+(?= +keyword\b)`?

Comment: Looks like that works!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer :)

Comment: You can use a capture group: `(\w+)\s+keyword$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zm6cXN/2/) Then just use group 1 in whatever you are using to run the regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/u2yxef/1/)

```
\w+(?= +keyword\b)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
this is some text keyword
```

#### Output

Match only shown below

```
text
```

---

### Explanation

- `\w+` Match one or more word characters
- `(?= +keyword\b)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches the following

  - `+` Match one or more spaces (note that there's actually a space before the `+` but SO doesn't show it)
  - `keyword` Match this literally
  - `\b` Assert position as a word boundary

Answer (score 0):

Use this [(?m)\w+(?=\h+keyword$)](https://regex101.com/r/IVBFxq/2) if *keyword* needs to be last on the line.