# Regex to match preceding word

Tags: python, regex

i'm attempting to extract the word 'Here' as 'Here' contains a capital letter at beginning of word and occurs before word 'now'.

Here is my attempt based on regex from  :

[regex match preceding word but not word itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117765/regex-match-preceding-word-but-not-word-itself?rq=1)

```
import re
sentence = "this is now test Here now tester"
print(re.compile('\w+(?= +now\b)').match(sentence))
```

None is printed in above example.

Have I implemented regex correctly ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)

Comment: Use `re.compile(r"\w+(?= +now\b)")`. The backslashes are being interpreted literally. Adding `r` before the string makes the string raw. Also, change `match` to `findall` or, to only match `Here`, change the regex to `[A-Z][a-z]*(?= +now\b)` and use `search`

Comment: Actually, there's another mistake: you have to use a raw string literal for the regex. `r'\w+(?= +now\b)'`

Comment: Also, that'll find "is", not just "Here".

Comment: And more, the `\w` will not differentiate the letter case.

Comment: Ok, I'm retracting my duplicate vote because there's too much wrong with this code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for the given example:

Regex:

```
re.search(r'\b[A-Z][a-z]+(?= now)', sentence).group()
```

Output:

```
'Here'
```

Explanation:

`\b` imposes word boundary

`[A-Z]` requires that word begins with capital letter

`[a-z]+` followed by 1 or more lowercase letters (modify as necessary)

`(?= now)` positive look-ahead assertion to match `now` with leading whitespace